# I am trying to run fbprophet and streamlit based web app on crypto-prediction, but the streamlit app does not recognize the prophet module

Tags: python, runtime-error, prediction, streamlit, facebook-prophet

I am trying to run fbprophet and streamlit based web app on crypto-prediction, but the streamlit app does not recognize the prophet module

This is the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet'
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "E:\Shubham\CPP Final Year Project\finadict-main\app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from prophet import Prophet
```

I have installed anaconda as it is easier to run fbprophet in anaconda
I have also created the environment named prophet39

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUvlu.png)

While running the streamlit application this error comes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWSY4.png)

What should i do now

I have visited all possible solution on internet and cannot find any solution to this!!

this is the code [code](https://github.com/subhayu99/finadict)

I am using windows by the way

I have tried all possible solution on the internet but not able to run this streamlit app

Comment: It looks like `streamlit` used in your terminal is not the one from your conda environment (see "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py"). Is `streamlit` installed on `prophet39`as well?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you also shared this on our forum – posting the solution here for visibility

> You have the wrong (outdated) package in your requirements.txt file.
> The latest package name should be prophet . And btw. remove the pystan
> package. And then change also the import name in you app.py file.